# ValueError, element is missing from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

**Context:** I'm connecting to SQL Server via Pyodbc to query the names of existing stored procedures in the database. After connecting, the following code executes and returns a list of tuples as follows:

```
  proc_name = 'load_activityid_report'

  costpoint_connection.autocommit = True

  query_existing_procs = "SELECT specific_name FROM costpoint_sandbox.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'"
  costpoint_connection_cursor.execute(query_existing_procs)

  procs = costpoint_connection_cursor.fetchall()

  print(type(procs))
  print(procs)
```

Here's the output:

```
<class 'list'>
[('parse_xml_lot_info', ), ('parse_xml_reqid_status_data', ), ('load_item_request_report', ), ('load_project_timecard_hours', ), ('load_activity_ids_masterlist_report', ), ('load_po_masterlist_report', ), ('load_project_descriptions_report', ), ('load_activityid_report', )]
```

Being a novice at Python I try to search the list of tuples for the **load_activityid_report** element (which clearly exists) with the following by appending it to a list, creating a tuple from that list and using the **Index()** method to search the list above for the tuple element:

```
  #Convert proc_name to list then to tuple
  proc_name_list = []
  proc_name_list.append(proc_name)
  proc_name_tuple = tuple(proc_name_list)
  print(proc_name_tuple)
```

output:

```
('load_activityid_report',)
```

**Question:** If the output above clearly shows that a tuple has been created with an element that matches why is it when I execute the **Index()** method I raise error below:

```
procs.index(proc_name_tuple)
```

> **ValueError: ('load_activityid_report',) is not in list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert procs from ***list of tuples*** into ***list of strings***

```
[''.join(i) for i in procs]
```

and from there get the index of *load_po_masterlist_report*

```
proc_name = "load_po_masterlist_report"
[''.join(i) for i in procs].index(proc_name))
```

Code:

```
procs = [('parse_xml_lot_info', ), ('parse_xml_reqid_status_data', ), ('load_item_request_report', ), ('load_project_timecard_hours', ), ('load_activity_ids_masterlist_report', ), ('load_po_masterlist_report', ), ('load_project_descriptions_report', ), ('load_activityid_report', )]

proc_name = "load_po_masterlist_report"

print([''.join(i) for i in procs].index(proc_name))
```

Output:

```
>>5
```

or you can try this:

```
procs = [('parse_xml_lot_info', ), ('parse_xml_reqid_status_data', ), ('load_item_request_report', ), ('load_project_timecard_hours', ), ('load_activity_ids_masterlist_report', ), ('load_po_masterlist_report', ), ('load_project_descriptions_report', ), ('load_activityid_report', )]
tup = ('load_activityid_report',)

for index, value in enumerate(procs):
    if value == tup:
        print(index, value)
```

Output:

```
7 ('load_activityid_report',)
```